# How to trigger setData event programmatically on SWT tree in VIRTUAL mode

Tags: tree, swt, virtual

is it possible to trigger setData event programatically on SWT tree in VIRTUAL mode?

Answer (score 1):

The `notifyListeners`-method in Widget does this.

```
tree.notifyListeners(SWT.SetData, <EventData>)
```

You have to construct and hand over a proper Event though.

Comment: This is not what i wanted, because to use this function, the event data must be created. anyway, i finally bypassed this problem.

Comment: Thanks, Fabian, it worked for me. +1! [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33869980/517705) is a short description of my case.

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to complement *Fabian Zeindl*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10626178/517705), which worked for me, in case these additional information are useful for someone.

When using the `SWT.VIRTUAL` flag, the elements get loaded as `TreeItem`s on-demand when scrolling them into the view. I wanted to select an element in a `TreeViewer` which has not yet been loaded as a `TreeItem` which makes `viewer.setSelection()` unable to work.
This means the given element has to be explicitly loaded as a TreeItem.

Here is a simplified sample code for this to work:

```java
final Tree treeViewerTree = treeViewer.getTree();
// we now assume that the indexOfElementToSelect value is set to a correct value (which is a lower value than treeViewerTree.getItemCount()!!)
TreeItem treeItem = treeViewerTree.getItem(indexOfElementToSelect);
final boolean isVirtualTree = (treeViewerTree.getStyle() & SWT.VIRTUAL) != 0;
if(isVirtualTree) {
    // trigger SWT.SetData event programmatically on SWT tree in VIRTUAL mode which loads the item explicitly
    Event virtualTreeEvent = new Event();
    virtualTreeEvent.index = indexOfElementToSelect;
    virtualTreeEvent.item = treeItem;
    // triggering SWT.SetData programmatically
    treeViewerTree.notifyListeners(SWT.SetData, virtualTreeEvent);
}

treeViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(........), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sam Zheng, two years down the road I certainly hope you have found your answer, but here it is for other seekers of the truth:

Use the `Tree.clear(index,boolean)` or `Tree.clearAll(boolean)` methods for root-level items, and `TreeItem.clear(index,boolean)` or `TreeItem.clear(boolean)` methods for items below the root.

Comment: This didn't work for me, it doesn't trigger `SWT.SetData` event. Fabian's  [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10626178/517705) did [work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33869980/517705) though.